# Получение количества участников групп VK API

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Доброго времени суток господа. Нужна ваша помощь в легкой задаче, увы, для меня из за нехватки опыта это оказалось сложным.

Работаю с VK API. Произвожу поиск групп по названию через `groups.search` (к примеру музыка/игры/фильмы), получаю список перебором `foreach ($data1['response'] as $item)` и вывожу название и картинку группы.

Затем мне нужно получить количество участников для каждой группы, это можно сделать через метод `groups.getMembers` введя `group_id`, но `group_id`я могу получить только во время перебора `foreach ($data1['response'] as $item)`. 
Если я так сделаю, то в принципе все работает, но скорость существенно падает, и страница начинает грузится до 3-5 секунд. Мне даже кажется, что скрипт не успевает до конца отрабатывать, потому что на некоторые группы я не получаю количества участников.

Может быть я что-то не так делаю, а мне кажется, что это так, и это можно реализовать по другому, но как я пока не знаю. Буду благодарен любой помощи или подсказке в какую сторону копать.

Вот мой код:

```
<?php 
    //Получаю список групп
    $url1 = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/groups.search?q=".$_POST['vkgroup']."&access_token=*MYTOKEN*");

    //ССылка на получение количество пользователей
    $url2 = "https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getMembers?group_id=";
    $data1 = json_decode($url1,true);     

    foreach ($data1['response'] as $item) {

        //Получаю список участников в группе
        $url3 = file_get_contents($url2.$item['screen_name']);
        $data2 = json_decode($url3,true);

        //Получаю цифрой количество участников
        $cuser=$data2['response']['count'];

        //Вывожу количество участников
        echo $cuser;
        //Вывожу картинку группы
        echo "<img src=".$item['photo']."> ";
        //Вывожу название группы
        echo $item['name']."<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Как вы потом работаете с этими данными? Есть ли возможность их кэшировать? Можно ли перенести получение количества пользователей на фронтэнд?

Comment: @br3t Мне не нужно его кешировать. У меня задумка вывести список групп -> выбрать подходящую группу -> на новой странице основываясь на выборе вывести последние 20 записей со стены сообщества через wall.get

Comment: Получение количества пользователей из клиента позволит распараллелить процесс, но тут надо на лимиты вконтакта смотреть.

Comment: @br3t будьте добры, расскажите по подробнее об этом. Хочется вникнуть во все это.

Comment: С примером для вас пока что не получается, так что даю ссылку на документацию: https://vk.com/dev/api_requests . Вы используете пп 4.2, можно попробовать 4.1 или 4.3.

Answer (score -1):

Вот такой (достаточно кривой, но работающий) пример у меня получился:

```js
var f = [];

var i = 0;
$("li").each(function() {
  var gid = $(this).attr("data-gid");
  var q = i;
  i++;
  var groupInfoUrl = "https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getMembers?callback=f[" + q + "]&v=5.60&group_id=" + gid;
  f[q] = function(result) {
    $("li").eq(q).find('span').text(result.response.count);
  }
  var script = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
  script.src = groupInfoUrl;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li data-gid="20629724">https://vk.com/habr - <span>...</span></li>
  <li data-gid="71741545">https://vk.com/googlerussia - <span>...</span></li>
</ul>
```